# Iterating through a series to add a character to a string using a while loop. The loop never breaks though on full data. What can I do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I have created a function that iterates through a column of strings with two distinct exact lengths. When subsetting my data into 100, I have no problems, but when I run the function on the full data ~230K, the while-loop never breaks. Below is the function:

```
def add_dash(df):
    n = 0
    results = []
    while n <= len(df[:-1]):
        if len(df[n]) == 7:
            results.append(df[n][:3] + '-' + df[n][3:])
            n += 1
        elif len(df[n]) == 13:
            results.append(df[n][:4] + '-' + df[n][4:6] + '-' + df[n][6:9] + '-' + df[n][9:])
            n += 1
        else:
            pass
    return(results)
```

Because I've tested it on a smaller set, I can't think of why the loop wouldn't end on a larger set. Any insight will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What if `len(df[n])` is not 7 or 13?

Comment: As a very basic debugging step, at the top of your loop, print `n` and `len(df[:-1])`.

Answer (score 0):

As @JohnGordon pointed out, if `len(df[n])` is not 7 or 13, you never update your value of `n`. To fix that:

```
def add_dash(df):
    n = 0
    results = []
    while n <= len(df[:-1]):
        if len(df[n]) == 7:
            results.append(df[n][:3] + '-' + df[n][3:])
            n += 1
        elif len(df[n]) == 13:
            results.append(df[n][:4] + '-' + df[n][4:6] + '-' + df[n][6:9] + '-' + df[n][9:])
            n += 1
        else:
            # Otherwise, n is always 0
            n +=1
    return(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase the 'n' value every loop

so:

```
while n <= len(df[:-1]):
    if len(df[n]) == 7:
        results.append(df[n][:3] + '-' + df[n][3:])
    elif len(df[n]) == 13:
        results.append(df[n][:4] + '-' + df[n][4:6] + '-' + df[n][6:9] + '-' + df[n][9:])
    n += 1
return(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
def add_dash(df): 
    n = 0 
    results = [] 
    while n <= len(df[:-1]): 
        if len(df[n]) == 7:       
            results.append(df[n][:3] + '-' + df[n][3:])
        elif len(df[n]) == 13:
            results.append(df[n][:4] + '-' + df[n][4:6] + '-' + df[n][6:9] + '-' + df[n][9:]) 
        else:
            results.append('')
        n+=1
    return(results)
```